# How to get InterfaceOrientation from iPhone (not DeviceOrientation)?

Tags: iphone, rotation, orientation

I've created a modalviewcontroller and all the subviews are created by code. When I'm testing the app, I find a problem. Then main cause of the problem is that an app shouldn't support UpsideDown orientation, but devices may happen to be in that orientation.

If I:

1. Rotate the device to Portrait orientation, and then to UpsideDown mode and presentModalView, the subviews in modalviewcontroller should appear the same as Portrait orientation.
2. Rotate the device to Landscape orientation, and then to UpsideDown mode and presentModalView, the subviews should be treated differently.

The above situation tells me that I should create subviews in modalviewcontroller according to previous InterfaceOrientation.

The problem is: How to get the previous screen's InterfaceOrientation? Getting the device orientation won't do any help in this situation.

PS: I'm writing a lib, I may give my users the interface to send me the "`toInterfaceOrientation`" from `-willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` but are there any ideas about how to get the orientation in my code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In any UIViewController you can access the property interfaceOrientation like this:

```
if (self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: **Note:** `interfaceOrientation` was deprecated in iOS version 8.0

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
   return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation);
}
```